# Python alternative to R RJDBC connection to SQL

Tags: python, vertica

I have a R code which connect to the Vertica database using RJDBC driver. The code is following:

```
library(RJDBC)
#for vertica save
user = "myuser"
pwd = "mypwd"

driver<- JDBC(driverClass="com.vertica.jdbc.Driver", classPath=Pathto thedriver")
connection<- dbConnect(driver, databasewithport, user, pwd)

sql_code = paste("SELECT .....")
mydata= dbGetQuery(connection, sql_code )
```

I am searching for a solution that helps do the same thing but using Python. I found the following [link](https://github.com/vertica/vertica-python), but do not understand which example to use and what else to do. As I understood here no need to connect to the RJDBC driver. Could you help to find the solution which gives the same output as R version.

The code below works well, however, data is retrieved as one value, to get another I need to change `....cur.fetchone()[ANYNUMBER])`. How can I get a data frame of the SQL code?

```
import vertica_python

conn_info = {'host': '127.0.0.1',
             'port': 5433,
             'user': 'some_user',
             'password': 'some_password',
             'database': 'vdb',
             'connection_load_balance': True}

# Server enables load balancing
with vertica_python.connect(**conn_info) as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT NODE_NAME FROM V_MONITOR.CURRENT_SESSION")
    print("Client connects to primary node:", cur.fetchone()[0])
    cur.execute("SELECT SET_LOAD_BALANCE_POLICY('ROUNDROBIN')")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need to install the vertica-python package:

```
pip install vertica-python
```

Next, you need to create a connection and perform the query. When retrieving the query results, you can (1) load them all or (2) process them one by one.

```
import vertica_python

conn_info = {'host': '127.0.0.1',
             'port': 5433,
             'user': 'myuser',
             'password': 'mypass',
             'database': 'vdb',
             'connection_load_balance': True}

with vertica_python.connect(**conn_info) as connection:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT NODE_NAME FROM V_MONITOR.CURRENT_SESSION")
    # (1) If you want to load all the results in-memory
    data = cur.fetchall()
    print(data)
    # (2) If you want to process one by one
    for row in cur.iterate():
        print(row)
```